# Question on "Nothing!!!"

Tags: discussion

There was a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/111508/19341) with the title like "This is absolutely nothing" or something like this, some days ago. The body was something like "Nothing!!!Nothing!!!Nothing!!!Nothing!!!...".

I flagged it, but after the first reload, it turned out to be a real question. What happenend there?  "Nothing!!!" can't even be found in the revision list.

Was this a bug or a joke?

Comment: I see "nothing, etc" in the [revision list](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/111508/revisions). I rolled back the edit as soon as I saw this vandalization. I think I caught it within a minute or two of the initial act.

Comment: Was it a *question* or *nothing*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is usually a time period (I believe 5 minutes) where edits do not go into the revision list.

So if the user posted Junk, and then within 5 minutes edited the question to NotJunk, it won't show in the revision history.

You were fast enough to catch it that time period.

Answer (score 1):

Some users prefer to "delete" their questions like that. Either after receiving an answer, or after coming up with their own answer.

I think it's best to rollback and leave a comment that the user should answer his own question; or flag the question for a moderator attention if you think that the thread itself should be deleted (e.g. there was no apparent activity except the OP's edit).